# Error while starting new IPython console in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, 64-bit, ipython, anaconda, spyder

While I was training a neural network with Pybrain, my computer crashed and I had to reboot it. Now Spyder, Python, IPython seem to work fine, however, when trying to open a new IPython console in Spyder, I get the following error:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\start_ipython_kernel.py", line 167, in 
from IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 48, in 
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 22, in 
from IPython.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\config\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from .application import *
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 19, in 
from IPython.config.configurable import SingletonConfigurable
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\config\configurable.py", line 14, in 
from IPython.utils.text import indent, wrap_paragraphs
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\utils\text.py", line 28, in 
from IPython.external.path import path
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\external\path\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from path import *
File "C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\path.py", line 122, in 
__version__ = pkg_resources.require('path.py')[0].version
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The error does not seem to interfere with the execution of Python scripts however I am wondering if I accidentally messed something up. I searched the internet but found nothing that could explain this error.
I am using Python 3.4.3 64 bit with the Anaconda 2.3.0 distribution.

Comment: is `setuptools` up to date?

Comment: @cel no it is 18.0.1. I should mention that the error has never come up before.

Comment: @cel let me try updating it

Comment: @cel appartently that was it, thanks. How did you notice that? (so that next time I can check this myself)

Comment: `pkg_resources` is a module provided by `setuptools` (you can find out by doing `print(pkg_resources)` after  importing it. I have seen similar errors before, so it was my first guess.

Comment: @cel Can you elaborate on your comment in an answer, so that it can be accepted as correct? I had the same problem and `pip install --upgrade --force setuptools` fixed it.

Comment: If a unique answer with both the solutions is provided I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: @mickkk, feel free to post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either upgrade `setuptools` or try
`pip install --upgrade --force setuptools` fixed it. Either one or the other should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct in that it is a setup tools problem, but I couldn't use `pip install --upgrade --force setuptools`, that complained about not being able to find easy-install.pth

Instead I was able to upgrade setuptools using easy-install itself with:
`easy_install --upgrade setuptools`, hope that helps someone who was stuck like me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. and setuptools did not fix my error.

finally, run

```
conda update path.py
```

fix my error. You could check this link: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2679

Answer (score 1):

```
conda update qt pyqt

conda update spyder

pip install -U spyder
```

This worked for me